# typeorm querybuilder including table not related to query?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I am currently trying to implement the following query in typeorm:

```
 select id,"createdAt", "updatedAt","deactivatedAt",(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM "deactivatedAt" - "createdAt")/3600 ) as lifespan
    from (
       select id,"createdAt", "updatedAt","deactivatedAt", (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM "deactivatedAt" - "createdAt")/3600 )as time
       from apartment_listing where active = false)as subquery
where subquery.time <24
```

For this, I have implemented the following code in in TypeScript:

```
    const mainQuery = this.repository
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select("subquery.id", "id")
      .addSelect("subquery.time", "time")
      .addSelect("subquery.created", "createdAt")
      .addSelect("subquery.deactivated", "deactivatedAt")
      .from(qb => {
        const sub = qb.select(
          "(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM listing.deactivatedAt - listing.createdAt )/3600 )",
          "time"
        )
        .addSelect("listing.deactivatedAt", "deactivated")
        .addSelect("listing.id", "id")
        .addSelect("listing.createdAt", "created")
        .addSelect("listing.active","active")
        .from(this.type, "listing")
        .where("listing.active = false")
        return sub;
      }, "subquery")
      .where("subquery.time < 24")
```

However, when executing this code the query generated by typeorm is incorrect and results in an infinite query which ends up using 100% of ram. The query generated is:

```
SELECT subquery.id AS "id", subquery.time AS "time", subquery.created AS "createdAt", subquery.deactivated AS "deactivatedAt" 
FROM "apartment_listing" "ApartmentListing", (SELECT "listing"."id" AS "id", "listing"."active" AS "active", "listing"."createdAt" AS "created", "listing"."deactivatedAt" AS "deactivated", (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM "listing"."deactivatedAt" - "listing"."createdAt" )/3600 ) AS "time" FROM "apartment_listing" "listing" WHERE "listing"."active" = false) "subquery" 
WHERE subquery.time < 24
```

As you can see, in the FROM clause it includes the `"apartment_listing" "ApartmentListing"` table as well as the subquery. If I copy and paste this query in PgAdmin, it also ends up in an infinite query, but if I remove that extra `"apartment_listing" "ApartmentListing",` table from the FROM clause, the result is successfull and I get the correct result.

Why is typeORM including this `"apartment_listing" "ApartmentListing",`? in my code implementation there is only one FROM and it points to the subquery. How can I get rid of that extra table so the query executes successfully?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of time has passed but i have just encountered this problem and I could fix it.

If you create the query builder from a repository ("ApartmentListing" in your case) then it seems it always add the table in FROM even if you call from() without adding the table.

To avoid this just create the query builder from something else. In your case from the manager:

```
const mainQuery = this.repository.manager
  .createQueryBuilder()
  ...
```